# Why is there so many TS errors even though it compiled fine?

Tags: typescript, tsc

I'm currently trying out TypeScript and combining it with some other JavaScript libraries. I can see the benefits of TypeScript when used with Vanilla JS and wanted to try out the whole idea of using various libraries in combination with declaration files (.d.ts) to have everything be in TypeScript.

I took the three.d.ts file off of the DefinitelyTyped repo so it should be an official and clean copy.

I ran `tsc app.ts` and my app.js file looks fine from the compilation. However, I got a string of errors essentially saying my syntax is wrong. Why is that so? I took it from the official repo for various definition files.

[image] 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new TypeScript 2.0, still in beta, declaration files .d.ts, can now be retrieved with, for instance, `npm install @types/three`.

So maybe there were some changes in some declaration files like three in order to comply with this new mechanism.

I would recommend you to try out this beta and check whether your issue is still here: `npm install typescript@beta -g`. Ensure your editor uses the most recent tsserver.ts (TypeScript API) in order to have an up to date Intellisense.

As a side note, no need to exclude the `three` directory since it is not a TypeScript library and you don't allow JavaScript files in your project (`--allowJs`)

Comment: Thank you! The compile errors are gone! being able to use `npm` to install definition files is much nicer. I'm slightly worried about the version because it's 0.0.17 but I guess that's the pains of trying it while it's in beta.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you want three.d.ts in your compilation directory. You want to reference the file but not have typescript compiling it. Did you try excluding it?

Comment: Why do I need to exclude it? I thought it has to be compiled with my app.ts file?

Comment: I'm looking at the stuff under project configuration:
http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html
The documentation is not really clear on what to do. I looked at the samples/examples and they simply left the jquery.d.ts file in the same directory as the other .ts files.

Comment: You want to have the reference tag in app.ts, but it doesn't need to be compiled with it because it doesn't contain any code. It just describes to typescript's compiler what your JS library looks like so it can validate that your code is consuming it correctly.

Comment: I agree that the documentation could be clearer. I've always excluded the typings folder when I install with the typings tool.

Comment: I see. Thank you! I didn't even know there was a typings tool. I'm like a days' worth of time into fiddling with TypeScript. Good stuff but kind of beginner unfriendly past the 'Quickstart' portion.

Comment: You're welcome! I've had to spend plenty of time searching on here and on blogs and such. It takes some time to sort out the tooling, but it's improving at a rapid rate.

Comment: One last quick question, my exclusion isn't working, is what I have here wrong? I put the .d.ts file into `typings` folder. Here's the tsconfig.json:
 `{
  "exclude": [
    "typings/**"
  ]
}`
It ignores the exclusion and still tries to compile it.

Comment: It doesn't support globs currently. You can just use the folder name. Like node_modules in the example. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: Simply `typings` doesn't work for me either :/ I'm not sure why

Comment: I added some screenshots to the original question for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is there so many TS errors even though it compiled fine?

Just because you get output JavaScript does not mean it compiled fine. The errors are still there. TypeScript tries its best to give you valid output JavaScript

## More

[Why TypeScript](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html)